# Dealing with numbers outside of uint256 range

Tags: decimal, solidity, integer-overflow

i am trying to build compound formula with solidity but I have came across a problem, given enough days, the amount is compounded, amount will overflow uint256 range.

I have read that as long as final result is in the range of uint256, it should be fine but it does not seem to be the case. here is the calculation that i am trying to do

**(100 * (100+8)^100) * 10^(6 - 2*100)**

as a formula it looks like this:

<sub>( BASE * ( (1 * 10^MULTIPLIER) + (YIELD * 10^MULITPLIER) ) ^ COMPOUNDED_DAYS ) * ( 10 ^ (DECIMALS - MULTIPLIER * COMPOUNDED_DAYS) )</sub>

as mentioned this is compound formula with 6 decimals, but when i run this in playground i get "0" as a result. what's the problem, and if there is problem how can i fix it?

Comment: I think your logic in code is wrong. You are getting 0 because it is default integer value

Comment: if you have `uint public var;` maybe you think you are updating this but you are actually not. so when you `return var` it will return default int value which is 0

Comment: https://ethfiddle.com/sGIQ46KItA here is the playground, i am returning the result directly, without assigning values

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your number becomes smaller than one and the integer turns it into zero

Comment: which part of multiplication are you referring to? because this operation "(100 * (100+8)^100) * 10^(6 - 2*100)" is not less than zero, and neither part of multiplication is either, second part is just less than 1

Comment: the whole calculation is smaller than 2^256-1 yes, but i think solidity just cant take 108 (100+8) to the power of 100 and thats when it breaks,

Comment: 100 * 108^100 * 10^-194 ...The result of these numerical calculations is smaller than 1

Comment: https://ibb.co/wYCkT9y

Comment: Right. My bad. The result is about 3^207 and this is a overflow

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The caret sign `^` represents a bitwise XOR - not an exponential multiplication. If you want to calculate "to the power of", use two asterisks `**`.

Example: "10 to the power of 2" in Solidity: `10 ** 2`

Comment: i use two asterisks in code, i chose caret sign because stackoverflow editor converts two asterisks as bold

Comment: I strongly believe this is just integer overflow, you can go to remix and run the math operation example, choose number 1,2,3 as compounded days instead of 100 and see that it runs alright

Comment: @Ratokl Thanks for the clarification, I saw the Ethfilddle in your question comment now... Yes, in this case, `(100+8)**compoundedDays` overflows the `uint256` type if you're calculating `108**100`. I'll try to come up with another answer.